# LLC Gain Curve by using SIMPLIS

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, llc-converter

Is it possible to use SIMPLIS to draw the gain curve of the LLC converter?

[image]

Because FHA analysis is not very accurate when the operating frequency is above the resonant frequency.

If it can, what kind of element I should use in SIMPLIS.

Comment: The real challenge will be in quantifying all the circuit parasitics. An ideal-only SIMPLIS simulation of the resonant tank and switching elements likely won't be any more accurate than the FHA. I wouldn't go too far pre-simulating; get a starting point, build it and sweep it to see the actual real-world performance.

Comment: @AdamLawrence, 
In the idea situation, SIMPLIS also can't do that?

Comment: It can - I'm just not sure if for a first approximation it will give you more useful information than the FHA would. The parasitic elements can dominate the performance of the circuit.

Comment: Hi @AdamLawrence,
Could you tell me how to do that?

Comment: https://www.simplistechnologies.com/support/downloads/examples

Comment: @AdamLawrence, 
The SIMPLIS example file doesn't have the gain curve.

Comment: But you can easily vary the frequency and plot the response yourself.

Comment: @AdamLawrence Do you mean to vary the frequency manually and draw the gain curve by myself? 
I can't get the gain curve by SIMPLIS itself?

Comment: @AdamLawrence
I solved the issue, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can draw a basic LLC circuit in any simulator, and feed it with sin wave while stepping frequency and/or load, and then you can observe the resonant tank gain at these frequencies similar to the graphs you attached. This way, what the simulator will show you, is not quite exact (no parasitics are considered), but it is good enough to design and predict the behavior of a physical LLC converter.

[image]

upload file [enter link description here](https://ufile.io/6ygdftc4)

Comment: Would be really nice if it's possible to draw a curve pack using different reflected load resistances (R1 in your circuit) which correspond to different Q's.